# Docker check IP adress of host

Tags: docker, licensing

I'm developing a licensing mechanism for Docker containers. Customers include a licencing key to unlock features in an app running in a Docker container. The licence key anchors with the host IP address.

How can I check if the Docker container is really running an a predefined Host IP address?

I thought about making a self request to this IP address on a certain port with a dynamically generated one-time secret

```
curl http://hostip:port?secret=xy
```

Is it reliable to make such self requests to verify the host IP address? I could not find any resources about that in the wild.

Comment: Generally speaking cloud providers use a health check endpoint to see if its responding, if it does not reply a healthcheck response in n seconds, the container orchestrator kills the current "running" container and instantiates another.

Comment: That doesn't seem like an especially reliable or secure way to identify a host machine.  Even without Docker, I can imagine running software in an environment like Amazon EC2 where I don't fully control the network environment and occasionally am forced to move things to different hosts; do I stop being able to use my licensed software when this happens?  I can't run it in an AWS autoscaling group?  Or can I run as many copies of it as I want, so long as I configure some private interface on my host with the right address?

Comment: @DavidMaze You're right. But our environment is a in-a-box Rancher 1.6 orchestrated system where customers can add Docker container but do not have the chance to change IP addresses or hostnames.